# storage.googleapis.com or storage.cloud.google.com for Signed URL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm signing a GET url in GAE and passing it to my client app so that it can directly download the file from google storage. If the client app sends the request to storage.googleapis.com, it gets a SignatureDoesNotMatch response. It works if the request is send to storage.cloud.google.com (still gets a 302, but I think it will work if redirected).

But if I generate the signed URL in a local app (not in GAE), then the request works (file gets downloaded) with storage.googleapis.com.

I would like to know which is the correct URL to send the signed url request and why the difference in behavior between GAE signed url and local app signed url.

Coming to PUT requests, Signed URL generated from GAE for PUT request does not work (403, 405) with either domains, though the local app generated signed URL works. I'm baffled with these strange behavior.

Comment: There are a couple of differences between local app and GAE servers.... very unfortunate, because it does make debugging a chore sometimes...

Comment: Julldar, any pointers on where to look for more info will be helpful.

Comment: I use the Logs API a LOT.  either this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/   or this  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/

and then I use the admin console.  If you want more info on the differences between dev and prod... I think you need non-customer facing documentation from Google :(.  God knows I've been looking for it

Comment: Do you mean logs contain some info which helps in understanding the difference between local and GAE env? I will certainly look into it.

Comment: well what blocks your code in production will definitely appear in your logs, yes.

Comment: Same here, identical code works ok locally, however when I sing PUT requests remotely (GAE, Android) I'm getting 403 all the time. @user3787910 - did you manage to get to the bottom of it? Ant findings would be appreciated.